# How to enable Out-Proc "State Sever" Session Mode in ASP.Net Core MVC

Tags: asp.net-core, model-view-controller, asp.net-core-2.1

Is there a way to configure out of process session state (using the Windows State server ) with ASP.NET Core MVC?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP NET Core MVC - How to configure Out of Process Session State?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38536012/asp-net-core-mvc-how-to-configure-out-of-process-session-state)

Comment: ASP.NET Core doesn't support State Server. Use Redis or SQL Server.

Comment: Thanks, Chris  for the Info